# I can't move images in my PowerPoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I have a PowerPoint file and all slide images are locked. Can anyone tell me how to unlock these images?

This is the [link to the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cazu79vhkvej5h4/Sustainable%20Organisations.zip?dl=0).

this is the link to the file without zip.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xrvdqboa10w8b77/Sustainable%20Organisations.pptx?dl=0

[image]

I also checked the slide master, but it didn't help.

Comment: Hi slhck, Thanks for the helping friend. Thanks soo much...

Comment: I just added the link to the file without zipping it. I hope now you can trust me and download it and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are set as static background images to your slides. If you right-click one of them and select `Format Background` you will see the `Fill` is set to `Picture or texture fill`.

[image]

You can click `Reset Background` if you just want to remove the image.

To edit the images, you'll have to take a screengrab of the image from Powerpoint, and edit that screengrab in something like Photoshop before pasting it back into Powerpoint.

Comment: Okay friend. Thank you so soo much. That is helpful to me. Great help. I like to rate your answer. But site is saying I must have 15 reputation to do this. Don't know how to do it. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your power point is protected. Change it by selecting the permission button shown below:

[image]

It will prompt you for a password so enter it and click ok. It should be that simple.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Eric. But it is not password protected. If you want I'll upload it without zip. Then you are able to download it and check for me? Also I have Powerpoint 2007.

Comment: Now I'm uploading my powerpoint file without zipping it. If any one can help me quickly, I really appreciate it. I must edit this powerpoint file within next few hours and give back to my client. Please help to me.